# Onenote for MAC: links to local files not working

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-onenote

I'm using the latest version of onenote for Mac and have tried to create links to local files on Mac using the following format:

```
file:///Users/Username/Desktop/why-how.pdf
```

However, I get the following error:
The application “Microsoft OneNote” does not have permission to open "why-how.pdf"

Any suggestions how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

OneNote was designed a cloud-based service that can be used across devices. Therefore the concept of a "local file" will not work.

The most obvious way around this, perhaps unfortunately if you're privacy conscious, is to embed the file into the OneNote page. That will insure it's available.

Another possibility is to make the file Internet-accessible, i.e. on your own web-page or Dropbox/Google docs, and link to it from there.

Answer (score 0):

MacOS automatically rejects links to files as a protection. However, if you hold the Command key while you click on the link to the file, the file will open.

I hope this still helps as the question was posted a while back ago. I was searching how to do this in 2017 and I couldn't find anything online, so I figured it out doing trial and error on Onenote for Mac.

In order to link to a local file you'd create a regular hyperlink, and in the destination enter: file:/// followed by the location of the file, for example:
file:///Users/Me/Desktop/Filename.extension

Then, to open the link, hold command key while clicking on the link.

Comment: Apologies. I just found out that this solution only works if you give permission to the app (Onenote) to access local files - since OneNote is Sandboxed in MacOS. And the only way I know to give permission is to previously drag and drop the file in question into OneNote - and this only works the first time.